# Migrating Google Play Services Location for Android O - supporting many devices

Tags: android, service, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi, google-location-services

I have a Service running which gets the users location periodically. I have just migrated all the code over to support Android O. Ie. I got rid of `FusedLocationAPI` and `GoogleApiClient`. I have replaced them with `FusedLocationProviderClient` instead, according to the guidelines here:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

My question is how should I make sure my app supports all android APIs - everything up to O. From my testing the new location API still works on versions earlier than O, but it seems that to run it, the users phone must have the newest update of Google Play Store. So it seems I should check play store version: `if (not newest play-store and version < Android-O) use fusedLocationAPI, else if (newest play-store and version>=O) use FusedLocationProviderClient.`
Anyone have any input on supporting as many devices as possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you're correct that the device must have the newest update of Google Play Store to use Android O apps. You may check this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html) which discussed on how to support different platform versions.

> In order to provide the best features and functionality across several Android versions, you should use the [Android Support Library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) in your app, which allows you to use several recent platform APIs on older versions.